# Как информацию из бд MySQL вывести на сайте?

Tags: php, mysql

Скрипт:

```
<?php$sdb_name      = "gateser8";$user_name     = "gateser8";$user_password = "**********";$db_name       = "gateser8";if (!$link = mysql_connect($sdb_name, $user_name, $user_password)) {    echo "<br>Не могу соединиться с сервером базы данных!<br>";    exit();}if (!mysql_select_db($db_name, $link)) {    echo "<br>Не могу выбрать базу данных<br>";    exit();}$str_sql_query = "SELECT * FROM product";if (!$result = mysql_query($str_sql_query, $link)) {    echo "<br>Не могу выполнить запрос<br>";    exit();}while ($mas = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {    foreach ($mas as $field) {        echo $field . " ";    }    echo "<br>";}mysql_close($link);?>
```

Выдает "Не могу соединиться с сервером базы данных!"

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php$host          = "localhost";// или тот ip, который указан в параметрах на хостинге$user_name     = "gateser8";$user_password = "**********";$db_name       = "gateser8";if (!mysql_connect($host, $user_name, $password)) {    echo "Cannot connect to MySQL!";    exit;}mysql_select_db($db_name);mysql_set_charset('utf8');//Ну это на всякий пожарный...//$result = mysql_query($str_sql_query);//$link - не нужен, запросы будут выполняться с последним открытым соединением?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. попробуйте сначала убедиться, что база данных работает: на сервере БД: ps ax | grep mysql
2. если сервер работает - попробуйте залогиниться из консоли (или phpmyadmin :) )mysql -h hostname -u user_name db_name -p
3. я думаю проблемы со вторым пунктом, потому что вроде php-mysql модуль уже стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, php-скрипт не может получить доступ к MуSQL. Либо сам MySQL не установлен, либо база данных 'gateser8' там не была заведена, либо пароль или юзер для доступа к "gateser8" неверно прописаны.

Comment: MySQL стоит на сервере, база данных там заведена в phpMyAdmin.Пароль и юзер верные. Из других источников выяснила, что в mysql_connect первый параметр должно быть имя хостанапример: "locsаlhost" или "127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

Толи я чего то не понял , но ваша база , на localhost или ip mysql_connect('localhost','..','..').  :-)

Answer (score 0):

вот рабочии скрипт попробуи его

```
 < ?php $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'здесь вставить пароль'); if (!$link) {     die('Ошибка соединения: ' . mysql_error()); } if (!mysql_ select_db("username")) {     echo "Ошибка выбора базы данных mydbname: " . mysql_error();     exit; } $sql = "SELECT * FROM `dle_post` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3"; $result = mysql_query($sql); if (!$result) {     echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . mysql_error();     exit; } if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {     echo "Запрос не вернул данных.";     exit; } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {     echo '<li>';     echo $row["xfields"];     echo '</li>'; } mysql_free_result($result); mysql_close($link); ? >
```